# regex to select specific character in line containing specific word

Tags: regex

I've some lines in multiple files in Intellij

want to replace specific character if it contains specific string in it

For ex

```
  Yum (shum pum bbbsih , ui Latin jhsg,), 
  Latin (shum pum bbbsih , ui num jhsg,),
  Yum (shum pum bbbsih , ui patin jhsg,),
```

select only lines which contains `Latin` string in it, and replace `),` with `"","",""),`

Expected output

```
  Yum (shum pum bbbsih , ui Latin jhsg,"","",""), 
  Latin (shum pum bbbsih , ui num jhsg,"","",""),
  Yum (shum pum bbbsih , ui patin jhsg,),
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Why do you need a regex for that? Like `if "Latin" in mystring:` then do the replace `mystring = mystring.replace("),", '"","",""),')`

Comment: Its a adhoc task, just need to search and replace above condition, not about running code

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: @cyberbrain, I'm able to select in groups <<^.*Latin.+(\\),+)$>>, but want to select specific character only ), if contains Latin in line

Comment: Is `'),'` always at the end of the string? If not, please add appropriate example(s) and indicate whether `'Latin'`, when present, always precedes `'),'` and whether `'),'` can appear more than once. Please answer by editing your question rather than answering in a comment. Also, please add a tag to identify which language or regex engine you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\bLatin\b.*\),` to match everything from the word `Latin` up to the last encounter of `),` within the line. You can capture the matched characters in a group. `(\bLatin\b.*)\),` Then in the replacement place the contents of capture group 1 back and add your replacement for `),`. `$1"","",""),`.

So in short, match `(\bLatin\b.*)\),` with replacement `$1"","",""),`.

[image: regex diagram]

<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%28%5CbLatin%5Cb.*%29%5C%29%2C)</sup>

This does assume a few things.

1. `Latin` is always placed before `),`
2. You want to match the last occurrence of `),` within the line. To match the first occurrence use `.*?` instead of `.*`.
3. `.` does not match the newline `\n` character. Meaning that the `s`/`m` (single/multi line) flag (depending on language) is disabled. If you do have the flag set, use `[^\n]*` or `[^\n)]*` instead of `.*` or `.*?`.
4. Some languages use `\1` instead of `$1` to use capture group data as a replacement.